# Problem opening infoWindow in @angular/google-maps map

Tags: angular, google-maps, angular-material

I am hitting a problem trying to open the `infoWindow` in an [@angular/google-maps](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/google-maps/map-info-window/map-info-window.ts#L35) control (part of angular/components).

I have followed a [tutorial](https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/google-maps-as-an-angular-component#mapinfowindow) as a first time user of this new functionality.  My setup is slightly different than in the tuturial.  I want to set just one marker and one `infoWindow` - rather than an array of markers.

I have setup a google-map control like this:

```
      <google-map height="500px" width="100%" [zoom]="zoom" [center]="marker.position" [options]="options">
        <map-marker #markerElement [position]="marker.position" (mapClick)="openInfo(markerElement)">
          <map-info-window>MyContent</map-info-window>
        </map-marker>
        <!-- <map-info-window>MyContent</map-info-window> -->
      </google-map>
```

(You can see from the commented out code in the above, that I have tried the placing of the `infoWindow` inside and outside the marker.  Neither has solved the problem and I do not know which is best...)

And here is the relevant component Typescript:

```
  @ViewChild(MapInfoWindow, { static: false }) infoWindow: MapInfoWindow

  marker;
  zoom = 8;
  options: google.maps.MapOptions = {
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
  }

  openInfo(marker: MapMarker) {
    console.log(marker);
    console.log(marker.position);
    this.infoWindow.open(marker);
  }

  addMarker() {
    this.marker = ({
      position: {
        lat: this.observation.locationLatitude,
        lng: this.observation.locationLongitude
      },
      label: {
        color: 'red',
        text: 'Marker label',
      },
      title: 'Marker title',
      options: { animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE },
    })
  }
```

The `openInfo(marker: MapMarker)` method is the most relevant bit, *I think*.

The `(mapClick)="openInfo(markerElement)"` event is correctly sent from the map control.  It logs in the console the 'marker' object.  However, it raises an error rather than opening the infoWindow.

The error is:

[image]

The error ('anchor.getAnchor is not a function') is raised on the `this.infoWindow.open(marker);` method.  I have also tried it without an argument like this: `this.infoWindow.open();`.

The API documentation is [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/info-window#InfoWindowOptions), and I have attached a screenshot of the relevant section:

[image]

I just cannot workout how to get it to work.  I might be missing the woods from the trees, but can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: If you are not committed to  `@angular/google-maps`, try `@agm/core`.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm actually trying to move away from `agm/core`.  I find the @angular/google-maps better so far. Just struggling with this issue (and it is most likely that I am missing something obvious :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**k Got it to work. DISCLAIMER - Cleaning required**

**Official docs :** https://github.com/angular/components/tree/master/src/google-maps

**1. I created a service to get my browser loc injected**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BrowserLocationService {

  constructor() { }

  public getPosition(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resp => {

          resolve({lng: resp.coords.longitude, lat: resp.coords.latitude});
        },
        err => {
          reject(err);
        });
    });

  }
}
```

**Rest was simply following this and some naming foo**

https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/google-maps/map-info-window/README.md

**2. Component**

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { GoogleMap, MapInfoWindow, MapMarker } from '@angular/google-maps';
import { BrowserLocationService } from './browser-location.service';

declare var google: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild(MapInfoWindow, { static: false }) infoWindow: MapInfoWindow;
  @ViewChild(GoogleMap, { static: false }) map: GoogleMap;

  browserLatLng: any = null;
  defaultMarker: any = null;
  zoom = 8;
  options: google.maps.MapOptions = {mapTypeId: 'terrain'};

  constructor(private locSvc: BrowserLocationService) {
    this.locSvc.getPosition().then(
      loc =>  {
        console.log(this.browserLatLng);
        this.browserLatLng = loc;
        this.addDefaultMarker();
      });
  }

  openInfo(marker: MapMarker) {
    this.infoWindow.open(marker);
  }

  addDefaultMarker() {
    this.defaultMarker = ({
      position: {
        lat: this.browserLatLng.lat,
        lng: this.browserLatLng.lng
      },
      label: {
        color: 'red',
        text: 'Marker label',
      },
      title: 'Marker title',
      options: { animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE },
    });
  }
}
```

**3. HTML**

```
<google-map height="500px" width="100%" [zoom]="zoom" [center]="defaultMarker?.position" [options]="options">
  <map-marker *ngIf="defaultMarker != null" #marker="mapMarker" [position]="defaultMarker?.position" (mapClick)="openInfo(marker)">
  </map-marker>
  <map-info-window>MyContent</map-info-window>
</google-map>
```

**`#marker="mapMarker"` had something to do with it**

Comment: `#marker="mapMarker"` solved the problem.  Thank you very much for your help. :) (and sorry for the late reply: it was late in the UK when I posted the question)

Comment: No worries man. I do this when I am absolutely bored with my life. I am not a die hard Stack Overflower :)